# Struts Spring integration null pointer exception

Tags: spring, hibernate, struts2, dependency-injection, nullpointerexception

I am trying to integrate Struts 2, Spring 3 (for DI) , Hibernate 4. Spring seems to do the injection but while referencing the injected object in execute method it throws null pointer exception.

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">

<filter>
     <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
     <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>


<context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/classes/SpringBeans.xml</param-value>
 </context-param>

<listener>
<listener-class>
  org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
</listener-class>
</listener>

</web-app>
```

applicationcontext.xml named as SpringBeans.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd">

<!-- Database Configuration -->
<import resource="DataSource.xml"/>
<import resource="HibernateSessionFactory.xml"/>

<!-- Beans Declaration -->
<import resource="EmployeeBean.xml"/>

 </beans>
```

HibernateSessionFactory.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd">

<bean id="sessionFactory"   class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">

<property name="dataSource">
  <ref bean="dataSource"/>
</property>

<property name="hibernateProperties">
   <props>
     <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
     <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
   </props>
</property>

<property name="mappingResources">
    <list>
      <value>com/example/bean/Employee.hbm.xml</value>
    </list>
</property> 

</bean>
</beans>
```

EmployeeBean.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans  http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd">

<bean id="registerAction" class="com.example.register.action.RegisterAction">
    <property name="registerBO" ref="registerBO" /> 
</bean>

<bean id="registerBO" class="com.example.boimplementation.RegisterBOImpl" >
    <property name="employeeDAO" ref="employeeDAO" />
</bean>

<bean id="employeeDAO" class="com.example.daoimplementation.EmployeeDAOImpl" >
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>
</beans>
```

Struts.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"  "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">

<struts>
<constant name="struts.action.extension" value=","/>
<constant name="struts.enable.DynamicMethodInvocation"
    value="false" />
<constant name="struts.devMode" value="false" />
<constant name="struts.custom.i18n.resources" value="global" />

<package name="register" namespace="/" extends="struts-default">

    <action name="register" class="com.example.register.action.RegisterAction"
        method="executeAction">

      <result name="success">pages/register.jsp</result>
      <result name="error">pages/register.jsp</result>

    </action>


     <action name="" class="com.example.register.action.RegisterAction"
        method="returnMethod">
             <result name="success">pages/register.jsp</result>
     </action>
</package>

</struts>
```

Action Class

```
        package com.example.register.action;

    import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ModelDriven;
    import com.example.bean.Employee;
    import com.example.bointerface.RegisterBO;

    public class RegisterAction implements ModelDriven<Employee>{
        RegisterBO registerBO;
        String test;

        private Employee emp = new Employee();

        public void setRegisterBO(RegisterBO registerBO){
            //registerBO.registerEmployee(emp);

            this.registerBO = registerBO;
            test = "Hello!!";
        }

        public RegisterBO getRegisterBO(){
            return registerBO;
        }

        public String executeAction(){
            System.out.println(test);

            if(registerBO.registerEmployee(emp))
                return "success";
            else
                return "error";
        }

        public String returnMethod(){
            return "success";
        }

        @Override
        public Employee getModel() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return emp;

        }


    }
```

In the above action the setRegisterBO() is getting invoked but while referencing the registerBO object in executeAction() it throws null pointer exception and the test String variable also prints null. Can someone tell what am I doing wrong here.

Comment: Have you done some investigation yourself? [This](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.2.x/docs/spring-and-struts-2.html) section on the Struts2 wiki covers Struts2 Spring Integration.

Comment: Thanks @M.Deinum, I forgot to add struts-spring-plugin.